# Create multiple DataFrames using data from an api

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm using the world bank API to analyze data and I want to create multiple data frames with the same indicators for different countries.

```
import wbgapi as wb
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import time as t_lib

#Variables

indicators = ['AG.PRD.LVSK.XD', 'AG.YLD.CREL.KG', 'NY.GDP.MINR.RT.ZS', 'SP.POP.TOTL.FE.ZS']
countries = ['PRT', 'BRL', 'ARG']
time = range(1995, 2021)

#Code

def create_df(country):
    df = wb.data.DataFrame(indicators, country, time, labels = True).reset_index()
    columns = [ item for item in df['Series'] ]
    columns
    df = df.T
    df.columns = columns 
    df.drop(['Series', 'series'], axis= 0, inplace = True)
    df = df.reset_index()
    return df 

 
list_of_dfs = []

for n in range(len(countries)):
    var = create_df(countries[n])
    list_of_dfs.append(var)
```

Want I really wanted is to create a data frame with a different name for a different country and to store them in a list or dict like: [df_1, df_2, df_3...]

EDIT:

I'm trying this now:

```
a_dictionary = {}

for n in range(len(countries)):
    a_dictionary["key%s" %n] = create_df(countries[n])
```

It was suppose to work but still get the same error in the 2nd loop:

```
APIResponseError: APIError: JSON decoding error (https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/sources/2/series/AG.PRD.LVSK.XD;AG.YLD.CREL.KG;NY.GDP.MINR.RT.ZS;SP.POP.TOTL.FE.ZS/country/BRL/time/YR1995;YR1996;YR1997;YR1998;YR1999;YR2000;YR2001;YR2002;YR2003;YR2004;YR2005;YR2006;YR2007;YR2008;YR2009;YR2010;YR2011;YR2012;YR2013;YR2014;YR2015;YR2016;YR2017;YR2018;YR2019;YR2020?per_page=1000&page=1&format=json)
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to notiv I noticed the problema was in "BRA" instead of "BRL".
I'm also putting here a new approach that works as well by creating a master dataframe and then slicing it by country to create the desired dataframes:

```
df = wb.data.DataFrame(indicators, countries, time, labels = True).reset_index()
columns = [ item for item in df['Series'] ]
columns
df = df.T
df.columns = columns 
df.drop(['Series', 'series'], axis= 0, inplace = True)
df = df.reset_index()
df

a_dictionary = {}

for n in range(len(countries)):
    
    new_df = df.loc[: , (df == countries[n]).any()]
    new_df['index'] = df['index']
    new_df.set_index('index', inplace = True)
    new_df.drop(['economy', 'Country'], axis= 0, inplace = True)
    a_dictionary["eco_df%s" %n] = new_df

 
for loop in range(len(countries)):

    for n in range(len(a_dictionary[f'eco_df{loop}'].columns)):
        sns.set_theme(style="dark")
        g = sns.relplot( data= a_dictionary[f'eco_df{loop}'], x= a_dictionary[f'eco_df{loop}'].index, y= a_dictionary[f'eco_df{loop}'].iloc[:,n], kind="line", palette="crest",
                    height=5, aspect=1.61, legend=False).set(title=countries[loop])

        g.set_axis_labels("Years")
        g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
        g.tight_layout()
```

At the end I used the dataframes to create a chart for each indicator for each country.
Many thanks for the help

Comment: What you create *is* a list of dfs, isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: It's giving me this error after the second loop: APIResponseError: APIError: JSON decoding error (https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/sources/2/series/AG.PRD.LVSK.XD;AG.YLD.CREL.KG;NY.GDP.MINR.RT.ZS;SP.POP.TOTL.FE.ZS/country/BRL/time/YR1995;YR1996;YR1997;YR1998;YR1999;YR2000;YR2001;YR2002;YR2003;YR2004;YR2005;YR2006;YR2007;YR2008;YR2009;YR2010;YR2011;YR2012;YR2013;YR2014;YR2015;YR2016;YR2017;YR2018;YR2019;YR2020?per_page=1000&page=1&format=json)

Comment: I believe the issue is that there is no country 'BRL'. Try 'BRA' instead.

Comment: Right! Thank you so much notiv. I also tried a different approach. that I will update that also works. Thanks